# what error is in the code snippet below?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, struts2

I have the following jsp code which uses struts tag:

```
<input type = "radio" 
    id = "<s:property value="name"/>" 
    name = "<s:property value="name"/>" 
    value = "<s:property value="value"/>" 
    <s:if test="fieldValue==null">
        <s:if test="defaultOption==true">
            checked="checked" 
        </s:if>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:if test="value==fieldValue">
            checked="checked" 
        </s:if>
    </s:else>
/>
```

Eclipse says that:
Start tag (input) not closed properly, expected >.
But I cannot find where is the error. Please help.

Comment: It is really an error, not a warning?

Comment: Eclipse say it is an error.

Comment: Try adding `>` instead of `/>`

Comment: Is the tag code is so long that Eclipse is confused ?

Comment: Eclipse is an open source.

Comment: Eclipse's JSP parser leaves a little to be desired sometimes; I generally turned JSP validation off to avoid spurious stuff like this. That said, this is illegible as written, and the functionality should be moved out of the input tag and wrapped up somewhere else. If it's used often, make a utility method.

Comment: It does look like a bug where the nesting of s:if threw it off.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an eclipse bug because with Netbeans there is no error

if you dont want to see the error with Eclipse (and in that case only) :

in the first if, put test like that :

```
fieldValue==null && defaultOption==true
```

and get rid of the internal if

it should be the same

PS : try to find a way to use s:radio maybe

Comment: But could you please explain more detail why ?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse complains because it does not accept tags (for example `<s:if>`) inside input tag, you can deactivate JSP validation as suggested in comments .

[Go to project properties and uncheck JSP Content Validator, then clean your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jinVv.png)

If you don't want to disable validation, here is a suggested solution:

```
<s:if test="fieldValue==null">
    <s:if test="defaultOption==true">
        <input type = "radio" id = "<s:property value="name"/>"  name = "<s:property value="name"/>" value = "<s:property value="value"/>" checked="checked" />
    </s:if>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:if test="value==fieldValue">
        <input type = "radio" id = "<s:property value="name"/>"  name = "<s:property value="name"/>" value = "<s:property value="value"/>" checked="checked" />
    </s:if>
</s:else>
```

Just as a note, your JSP code give same result(I guess it's just for illustration :) ).